# how can i get a response when i post a form to a specific api

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

i have made an api to get data and save it into mongo db

```js
const userDB = require('./model/user')

app.post ('/signup', function (req, res){
    userDB.find({username: req.body.username}).
    then (result=>{
        if (result.length == 0) {
            bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, function (err, hash){
                if (err) {
                    res.status(404).json ({
                        message : err
                    })
                }else{
                    const user = new userDB ({
                        username: req.body.username,
                        password: hash
                    })
                    user.save().
                    then(result =>{
                        res.status(200).json({
                            message : 'user had been created'
                        })
                    }).
                    catch(err=>{
                        res.status(404).json({
                            message : err
                        })
                    })
                }
            })
        }else{
            res.status(200).json({
                message : 'user already exist'
            })
        }
    }).
    catch(err=>{
        res.status(404).json ({
            message : err
        })
    })
})
```

and i have made a html register form to post register information to api

how can i receive the api response in client side to make an alert that the operation has succeed or not

Comment: Can you please specify what client you're using (ReactJS, ExpressJS...)

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you use on the client side, if you use vanilla javascript:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    // register success
  }
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 404) {
    // register failure
  }
};
xhttp.open("POST", "/signup", true);
xhttp.send();
```

You should consider using appropriate status codes, 404 means page not found, which is clearly not true. In your case 500 (internal server error) seems to be the correct one where you used 404.

Comment: but i want to post information only by the form not by xmlhttprequest

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a response from your node api to the client who send the request, just use `res.send` in your api.

```
res.send(**your data**)
```

then, in your client, just `await` for the response or use `.then`

Comment: i am just using a form not a fetich function